# can we Run Whats app web in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, whatsapp

Hello guys this is  just a query you guys let me know  can we run web.whatsapp.com  in a  component in react ? And use it as a widget  is this possible does whats app allow x-frame-options.   Please provide a link of whatever reference any one  is having ? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Whatsapp sets the `x-frame-options` to `DENY`. You also can't use any of their endpoints in a custom react component since all of them use the CORS headers to only allow calls from `web.whatsapp.com`